# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First – Table per Hierarchy without Discriminator Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I want to break up a table in different models to use in different views.

```
public class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class UserFull : User
{
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class theDBtoUse : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserFull> UserFull { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("user_id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.FirstName).HasColumnName("user_firstname");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r. LastName).HasColumnName("user_lastname");

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("user");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserFull>().Property(r => r.Street).HasColumnName("user_street ");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserFull>().Property(r => r.Country).HasColumnName("user_country");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

When I use this. Said that it lacks the 'Discriminator' column

```
theDBtoUse theDB = new theDBtoUse();

var theUserToMatch = (from r in theDB.UserFull
                                  where r.Street.ToLower() == "astreetname"
                                  select r);

if theUserToMatch () == 0) // throws - Invalid column name 'Discriminator'
```

Can anyone help me with how to use different models against the same database table. and please do not suggest other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. You are abusing entity inheritance.

First of all you can never have TPH without discriminator column because you can never have two entities mapped to the same database record. It means that your record in database could be only `User` or `UserFull` but never ever both of them.

You should differ between entity and view model. Those two are not the same. Entity is what you want to persist and it is complete collection of data. View model is subset of one or more entities presented on view.

In your case the most obvious solution is `User` class with all fields and projection query to custom non-mapped view for limited user view.

Mapped entity and full view model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Non mapped limited view model:

```
public class UserLimitedView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class theDBtoUse : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("user_id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.FirstName).HasColumnName("user_firstname");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r. LastName).HasColumnName("user_lastname");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Street).HasColumnName("user_street ");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Country).HasColumnName("user_country");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var data = context.Users
                  .Where(...)
                  .Select(u => new UserLimitedView
                      {
                          Id = u.Id,
                          FirstName = u.FirstName,
                          LastName = u.LastName
                      });

var fullData = context.Users.Where(...);
```

EF code first doesn't have build in mapping support for mapping projections directly. In case of EDMX projections can be part of mapping via QueryView.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Not the answer I was hoping for but now I know how it works /Joakim

Comment: What if I want to insert a `UserLimitedView` object into DB, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your derived class with

```
[Table("tablename")]
```

Please, find a complete project below (just add an app.config)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace Bookstore
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UsersFull")]
    public class UserFull : User
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        static Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserFull> UsersFull { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new Context();
            context.Database.Delete();
            context.Database.Create();


            var userFull = new UserFull { Country = "Alabama", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Capioca", Street = "astreetname" };
            context.UsersFull.Add(userFull);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var theUserToMatch = (from r in context.UsersFull
                                  where r.Street.ToLower() == "astreetname"
                                  select r);

            if (theUserToMatch.Count() != 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Yeah! No Invalid column name 'Discriminator' exception");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question: I just read you wish to use a single table.